# What is a behavior of a class with two interfaces registered as singleton in simple injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a following class:

```
public class UserService : IUserService, IObserver<User>
```

I have registered `IUserService` as a Singleton to `UserService`. After that I do register the `IObserver` this way:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IObserver<>),
    container.RegisterAll,
    typeof(IObserver<>).Assembly);
```

So now if I inject `IEnumerable<IObservable>` to my composite pattern and when I will enumerate will I get the same object as when resolving `IUserService`?

It seems that it works this way (only one object of `UserService` exists) at least if I resolve the `IEnumerable` first. I was not able to find that in the documentation, but is this the feature that Simple Injector supports or it's a coincidence that can be changed at any time? And if yes, then I guess this behavior is the same for any two or more interfaces, not necessarily open generic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you see is by design and described in the documentation for the [container.RegisterCollection(Type, IEnumerable) method](https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/?topic=html/M_SimpleInjector_Container_RegisterCollection_2.htm) (`RegisterAll` in v2.x):

> Registers a collection of serviceTypes, whose instances will be
>   resolved lazily each time the resolved collection of serviceType is
>   enumerated. The underlying collection is a stream that will return
>   individual instances ***based on their specific registered lifestyle***,
>   for each call to `IEnumerator<T>.Current`. The order in which the types appear in
>   the collection is the exact same order that the items were registered,
>   i.e the resolved collection is deterministic.

Although the API documentation states this, I must admit that the documentation isn't very clear about this. There are [other places](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#configuring-simple-injector) where this behavior is described, but this information is a bit buried deep down in the docs.

But basically, the API is designed to allow this:

```cs
container.Register<ILogger, DefaultLogger>(Lifestyle.Transient);
container.Register<SqlLogger>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<FileLogger>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.RegisteCollection<ILogger>(new[] {
    typeof(MailLogger), 
    typeof(SqlLogger), 
    typeof(FileLogger),
    typeof(ILogger)
 });
```

This configuration has a collection of `ILogger` implementations, where the first element in the collection (`MailLogger`) will be a transient (in case the `LifestyleSelectionBehavior` isn't overridden), the second (`SqlLogger`) will be Per Request, the third (`FileLogger`) will be a singleton, and the fourth element will resolve a `DefaultLogger` as transient.

> it's a coincidence that can be changed at any time?

No, this is documented, tested, and supported. Although we will (by [definition](http://semver.org/)) introduce breaking changes in the next major release, it's very unlikely that we would change this behavior.

**UPDATE**: Note that this behavior hasn't changed in v3.

> when you have two interfaces on the same class: will it will be the same class if I register the second interface on the same class?

No, it will not. This will in fact lead to a [Torn Registration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html), which is something the [Diagnostic Services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) warn about. Basically, if you do this:

```
container.Register<IFoo, FooBar>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<IBar, FooBar>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

In this case the container will resolve two separate instances for `FooBar`. That's because Simple Injector focusses on the registration (the abstraction), not the implementation (compared to Unity for instance, that works the other way around). In case you need exactly 1 `FooBar`, you will have to do the following:

```
var registration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<FooBar>(container);

container.AddRegistration(typeof(IFoo), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IBar), registration);
```

In your case that means that you will have to do this:

```
var registration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<UserService>(container);

container.AddRegistration(typeof(IUserService), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(UserService), registration);

container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IObserver<>),
    new[] { typeof(IObserver<>).Assembly });

// Simple Injector v2.x syntax
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IObserver<>),
    container.RegisterAll,
    typeof(IObserver<>).Assembly);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this I understand and it is documented, but I was interested in a singleton behavior when you have two interfaces on the same class: will it will be the same class if I register the second interface on the same class?

Comment: By the way, regarding the RegsiterAll I have found something that seems to be not documented or maybe I do not fully understand it. I do call RegisterAll inside RegisterManyForOpenGeneric and I do not register the classes before that and then I get transient registration by default. The documentation for BatchRegistrationCallback  has an example of how to register items as singleton, but it does not mention that if you do just RegisterAll (which is supposed to do the IEnumerable only) then you have transient enumerable elements by default.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: The documentation doesn't state this, because transient is [the default behavior](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/extensibility.html#overriding-selection-behavior). But it would be good if we would document this explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for updated comment, now I see that I did it wrong. (I guess you meant IObserver<User> in the second AddRegistratrion). I am still stuck though with my scenario as it requires few classes with multiple interfaces that should be singletons: Foo: IFoo, IObservable<Foo>, Bar:IBar, IObservable<Foo>, is it possible to register this somehow that Foo and Bar are proper Singletons and the same singletons are returned when I do IEnumerable<Foo> in the Composite constructor?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: Yes,sorry,that should have been `IObserver<User>`. Changed that. It seems btw that the Diagnostic Service does not spot the configuration error of your particular case. I created [a work item](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/20997) for that. About your last question: I'm not sure I understand what it is you want. To prevent having a long discussion here in the comments, it would be good to move this to the [Simple Injector forum](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions). You have more space to explain what it is you want and I have more space to comment.